# Extract docstring form a python file using grep or awk

Tags: python, regex, awk, grep

I want to extract all docstrings from my python file using grep or awk. 
I tried

```
cat test.py | grep """[\w\W]*?"""
```

But I see no output.
Say the the test `test.py` looks like this.

```
import libraries

class MyClass(object):
    """Docstring to this class. 
       second line of docstring."""

    def myClassMethod(a,b):
        """Docstring of the method. 
           another line in docstring of the method."""
        return a + b
```

Then the output should be all that is enclosed in triple quotes.

```
"""Docstring to this class. 
second line of docstring."""
"""Docstring of the method. 
another line in docstring of the method."""
```

Comment: We're gonna need more details, like input sample and expected output.

Comment: I added the test case and fixed typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to extract docstrings from Python code is via actual Python parser (the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ast

with open('/path/to/file') as f:
    code = ast.parse(f.read())

for node in ast.walk(code):
    if isinstance(node, (ast.FunctionDef, ast.ClassDef, ast.Module)):
        docstring = ast.get_docstring(node)
        if docstring:
            print(repr(docstring))
```

Run on your sample will output:

```
'Docstring to this class. \nsecond line of docstring.'
'Docstring of the method. \nanother line in docstring of the method.'
```

---

Just for fun, we can do also do it with GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v FPAT="'''.*'''|"'""".*"""' '{print $1}' file
"""Docstring to this class. 
       second line of docstring."""
"""Docstring of the method. 
           another line in docstring of the method."""
```

Comment: I had found this method, but I was wondering if this could be done using grep or awk

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it over Python version, but take a look at the awk approach I just added.

Comment: Thanks a lot this satisfied my curiosity

Answer (score 1):

With P(perl) grep you can do the following:

```
grep -Poz '"""[^"]+"""' test.py
```

Output:

```
"""Docstring to this class. 
       second line of docstring.""""""Docstring of the method. 
           another line in docstring of the method."""
```

Comment: I am getting an error `grep: unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz`

Comment: Mine is `grep (GNU grep) 2.24`  if we use something other than perl regex does it work.